# Excel - Mixing Relative and Absolute References in Tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want understand how to mix absolute and relative references in an Excel table so that one end of the reference is 'anchored', a table equivalent to the below range reference.

**($A$1:A1)**

An example of where I use this notation is for creating a running total column as follows:

Row 1 contains headers.

Column A contains values to be summed.

Formula entered in cell B2, filled down the column.

**=SUM($A$2:A2)**

Please help me understand if this is possible in table notation.

Many thanks, Tym

Comment: Did you try it?  Did it not do what you Expect?  There is nothing wrong with this formula.

Comment: Or are you looking for something like: `=SUM(Table1[[#Headers],[Price]]:[@Price])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when using structured references and SUM, Anchor the Header as the start:

```
=SUM(MyTable[[#Headers],[Value]]:[@Value])
```

Sum ingnores the text.

[image]

---

When working with formula that do not ignore text then we need to use OFFSET:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(MyTable[[#Headers],[Value]],1,0):[@Value])
```

[image]

Comment: Scott, many thanks that works for me. I really appreciate your swift response, Tym

Comment: Great solution!  For table references, if you copy/paste the formulas, all table references remain absolute.  If instead you drag the lower-right corner to copy the formula to other cells, normal single cell table references are relative while multi-cell references (e.g. a span of columns or the header row) are absolute.  This workaround calls a single table cell using the format of a multi-column reference, for example, from the `[@Value]` cell to the `[@Value]` cell.  So the relative `[@Value]` is called as absolute `[Value]]:[@Value]`.

Answer (score 0):

> Please help me understand if this is possible in table notation

No you can't achieve the same with structured references, or can either refer to the actual row or the whole column, no other possibility.